# How to get a signed transaction string when I've already got the r,s&v from signing?

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet

The signed transaction geneated by MyEtherWallet has a length of 200(chars) or more, but after signing, the total length of r(32 bytes),s(32bytes)and v , about 130 in chars is far less than that. So there must be some kind of encoding to put r,s&v together to form the signed transaction string.  I've tried RLP, but the length is still far too short, not to mention the correction. What is this encoding?  I'm writing an iOS app unable to use web3.js so I need to know the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the RLP-encoded representation of the following fields:

- nonce (32 bytes)
- gas price (32 bytes)
- gas limit (32 bytes)
- to address (20 bytes)
- value (32 bytes)
- data (variable length, often empty)
- v (single byte)
- r (32 bytes)
- s (32 bytes)

Source: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/index.js#L50

Comment: This step is already done:  first ,RLP-encode the above fields you mentioned, then Sha3 hash the encoded data,  and then  use secp256k1 to  to sign the hashed data. The signing result is stored in the structure with components of r,s and v. This is how far I've gone.

Comment: Yes, to sign a transaction, you encode all of that with the chain ID in `v`, and zeroes in `r` and `s`, hash, and sign. Then to get the final transaction to send, RLP-encode again using the values of `v`, `r`, and `s` obtained from signing.

Comment: It sounds like you're pretty much there, just need to RLP-encode again.

Comment: "To get the final transaction to send, RLP-encode again using the values of v, r, and s obtained from signing. "    ---- I RLP-encoded the list of [r, s, v], and transfer the output data to hex string, but what I got is not as precise as the MyEtherWallet has generated. Btw, with the same values of fields to process, I got the same hash but got different r and s every time, however mew always generates the exact same signed transaction with the same fields. I donno why. I am a newbie.Thank you so much for help!

Comment: You need to RLP-encode _the whole transaction_: nonce, gas price, gas limit, etc.

Comment: As to why MEW always generates the same signature, it looks like rather than a pseudorandom _k_ value, they use HMAC-DRBG to deterministically determine a _k_ based on the hash that's being signed. My guess is that the library you're using chooses a random _k_. Both options are fine, though using a deterministic _k_ is a little better in the case of a bad pseudorandom number generator. (If _k_ values are reused, it can compromise the private key used for signing.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You save me half a week of time!  Finally I could find my tx broadcasted to the net!